# cout fails to give output probably due to inline assembly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline-assembly, cout, cl

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt. The inline assembly code is simple division and remainder. There is no error in compilation using the command `cl /EHsc filename.cpp`. Absolutely nothing is displayed on the screen. It takes up to 4 seconds of runtime.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=10,y=20;
    int z=0,r=0;
    //z=x/y
    //r=x%y
    __asm
    {
        MOV EAX,x
        IDIV y
        MOV z,EAX
        MOV r,EDX
    }
    cout<<"z = "<<z<<"\tr = "<<r<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see nothing in this code that would interfere with `cout`. You will just have to trace into the code with a debugger.  But why are you using inline assembly at all, and not simply using the `/` and `%` operators in normal C++ code? Let the compiler optimize for you as needed.

Comment: If you're trying to be efficient, use [`std::div`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div)

Comment: I am learning basic inline assembly and that is why using it.

Comment: 1. Use the debugger. 2. Forget inline assembly 3. Forget assembly

Comment: You might need to tell the compiler that you are clobbering `EAX` and `EDX`.

Comment: How do I do that ? @G.Sliepen

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone. Adding just one line `CDQ` just before `IDIV y` did the job. @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis "Forget assembly" What about if you want to be a engineer developing drivers or close to the bone protocols on on embedded hardware. Or if you want to develop on OS kernels. Or if you want to write compilers? Or if you want to work on HPC? Or just to get a better understanding on what happens under the hood to write better abstractions? Or what if you want to write a new programming language?

Comment: @G.Sliepen: This is MSVC, not GNU C inline asm.  MSVC parses your asm and figures out which registers you touch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `CDQ` between the `MOV EAX,x` and the `IDIV y` instructions.  Without it, the `EDX` register has an unknown value in it, possibly resulting in a divide overflow.  The `CDQ` instruction will sign extend `EAX` into `EDX`.

```
MOV EAX,x
CDQ
IDIV y
```

Comment: @MohammadShahwez: Also worth mentioning that this inline asm is totally pointless; the compiler will do this optimization for you (using both outputs of one `idiv`), or better not even using `idiv` for a compile-time-constant divisor.  (Even with a runtime variable dividend.)  Using MSVC inline asm introduces a store/reload of both outputs.  See [What is the difference between 'asm', '\_\_asm' and '\_\_asm\_\_'?](//stackoverflow.com/a/35959859)

Comment: @MohammadShahwez: Also worth mentioning: under a better OS, you'd see the program crash from the divide exception.  e.g. on a Unix-like OS such as Linux, the OS would kill your process with a SIGFPE arithmetic exception, and the command line shell would report that fact.  Under Windows, maybe try Powershell in case it's just `cmd` being bad and not reporting abnormal program termination.